# JavaScript Object Parameter - Seems Legit

Tags: javascript, function, object

There are many JavaScript functions out there that accept an object directly here are some examples. This is isn't specific to either of these functions jquery's `$.ajax()` or the nodejs module `request()`, both are just examples.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  data: {'hello':'world'},
})

request({
  method : "post",
  body : "hello world",
});
```

I just tried something that I thought would work and it was a more elaborate version of this.

```
request({
  method : function(){
    return "post";
  },
  data: {'hello':'world'},
});
```

To my surprise it didn't work. Neither does this.

```
var m = function(){
  return "post";
};

request({
  method : m,
  data: {'hello':'world'},
});
```

Am I missing something? Is there some way to get a generated function into these objects? I'd love some feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to pass a function here, you want to pass its return value.

```
request({
  method: (function() {
    return "post";
  })(),
  data: {'hello':'world'}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute the function and use the return value, not the function itself.

```
var m = function(){
  return "post";
};

var data = function() {
  return {'hello':'world'};
}

request({
  method : m(),
  data: data()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the function when the document loads like I've got it below. This will make m = 'post'

```
var m = (function(){
  return "post";
})();

request({
  method : m,
  data: {'hello':'world'},
});
```